# Firebase Analytics: Show Average of 'Value' Parameter and average of time like 'hh:mm:ss' in the Console for events sent from Android app

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

I have been exploring Firebase Analytics for Android and found that the Console's dashboard displays User Engagement event that shows average screen time like 'hh:mm:ss' and also an average number for the 'Value' parameter by getting the sum of the parameter and dividing it by the 'Count' of the event. For my custom events, it displays both the Count and the sum of the Value parameter but nowhere shows the average. This also applies for the time parameter. So basically, I want to:

1. show the average of the Value parameter
2. show average time for an event as 'hh:mm:ss'
3. Know how to properly send 'hh:mm:ss' formatted time parameter from Android or any other platform

I am sending events like below:

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();

params.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.START_DATE, new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ").format(loadingStartTime));
params.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.END_DATE, new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ").format(loadingEndTime));
params.putDouble(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.VALUE, loadingTimeInMillis/1000);

mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent("app_loading_event", params);
```

Thank you ahead, any help will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a couple of days search, it seems like these cannot be done by Firebase Analytics. The only options remaining is to link the Firebase Project with Google Cloud BigQuery and then query and find the ave(value) and mentioned timestamp. To visualize the queried data, export the BigQuery dataset to Google Data Studio and design your own analytical dashboard using the imported dataset. I have then embedded the Data Studio graphs in our website.

https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mobile/mobile-firebase-analytics-bigquery
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/visualize-data-studio

and here is a very useful tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pxNrkjBeHpw

This sounds very basic for Google Cloud Developers, but it was new for me.